# SEO for blog with async content

Tags: seo, web-crawlers

I have a blog website and I want to perform Search Engine Optimization on it.

My website, which is built in Angular 8, takes part of the URL route and uses that to search for the blog. For example, if one visits `example.com/blog/dynamic-import` the page will do a HTTP request to find `example.com/assets/blog/dynamic-import/dynamic-import.md` and then adorns the content.

I plan to use a `sitemap.xml` to direct the crawlers to the HTML pages, instead of the static markdown.

I am aware that the initial page load is the most important for the web crawlers. I understand it as the web crawler doesn't wait around for long before it leaves the page.

I am worried that, because this is a separate async operation that takes place after the page is loaded, that web crawlers will not pick up the content of the blog, and hence will not detect the keywords.

#### Question:

Is there any way I can make sure the content is loaded before the crawler analyses the page?

Is there some other way that I can get the content of the static assets files to contribute to the content of the blog pages for the purpose of SEO (some sort of reference for example)?

Comment: Check the guide of Google Get started with dynamic rendering = https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/dynamic-rendering

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into server side rendering. I use React and [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/), but I'm unsure if Next would work with Angular or if there are any similar libraries for it.

It's likely you might have to rewrite some of your code if you switch to SSR though.

Comment: Thanks. I am actually deploying with zeit now. So I just have to find out about angular universal with it. I am also going to use an angular resolver service to pre fetch the blogs. That's my plan now.